# Confounding variables

Tags: epidemiology

Suppose we want to study the association between alcohol consumption and cancer. If we include people who also smoke (a confounder), would this lower the relative risk of cancer for alcohol drinkers? If we only include people who do not smoke, this would increase the relative risk of cancer for alcohol drinkers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: edit your post to say "would this lower/increase the **estimate** of the relative risk"

The answer is then **YES**.

To understand the mechanics of why, you'll want an elementary primer on linear regression and conditional expectations.  I'd recommend using google to look for lecture notes on slides, as these are usually better intros than textbooks, which often aim for completeness over intelligibility to newbies.